# Divisibility by $8$ and $9$.

Tags: divisibility

How many ordered pairs $(a,b)$ exist such that the four-digit number, $a04b$, is divisible by both $8$ and $9$?

How should I approach this? (without modular arithmetic?)

Comment: Remember the rules for divisibility with $8$ and $9$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the number $\overline{a04b}$ is divisible by $8$ if and only if $\overline{04b}$ is divisible by $8$, so we must have $b=0$ or $b=8$.Notice that the numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9\}$ are a complete residue system $\bmod 9$, so it doesn't matter which case we pick,there is only one option for $a$.

So there are two such numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much, however I would like to know if there is a way to do so without modular arithmetic, sorry for not mentioning earlier.

Comment: Oh, of course there are, but using modular arithmetic is very simple as you can see.

Comment: @SriDevulapalli Without modular arithmetic, it's still not bad: Having found possibilities for $b$, just look at $\overline{a040}$ and $\overline{a048}$ separately. They are multiples of $9$ if and only if their digits sum to a multiple of $9$. For each, there is only one possibility for $a$ (as is pointed out in this answer, just with a different language).

Answer (score 1):

We can write:

$$a04b=1000\cdot a+100\cdot 0+10\cdot 4+b$$

Once $1000$ and $40$ are divisible by $8$ then $b$ must be divisible by $8$ and then $b=8$.

For division by $9$ we can write:

$$a048= 999\cdot a + a+40+8$$

Once $999$ is divisible by $9$ then $a+48$ has to be divisible by $9$. Once $0\le a\le 9$ the only value that fits is $a=6$.